# Tool for downloading URL files/images into an archive or directory

Tags: download-manager

I need a simple tool for downloading lots of URLs I took from my `imgur.com` uploaded images and output them in a directory or archive. I've separated each URL in lines into a text, in the `https://i.imgur/id.png` form (redirecting to an image).

Comment: Never used myself, thus only a comment: You might want to look into the [ZIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIM_(file_format)) format. This is designed for internet archival.

Answer (score 0):

Free download manager (FDM) can handle this no problems, leeching websites is part of its FTP site manager component. Not sure about recent versions because i'm happy with 3.9.6 b1614.